# what are the difference between for loop & for each loop in php

Tags: php

What are the differences between the `for` loop and the `foreach` loop in PHP?

Comment: *(reference)* http://de2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php and http://de2.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: I suggest you look at some documentation on both of the loop-types. There are some fundamental differences. Or do you have a specific problem? If so, please clarify in your question.

Answer (score 14):

Foreach is great for iterating through arrays that use keys and values.

For example, if I had an array called 'User':

```
$User = array(
    'name' => 'Bob',
    'email' => 'bob@example.com',
    'age' => 200
);
```

I could iterate through that very easily and still make use of the keys:

```
foreach ($User as $key => $value) {
    echo $key.' is '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

This would print out:

```
name is Bob
email is bob@example.com
age is 200
```

With `for` loops, it's more difficult to retain the use of the keys.

When you're using object-oriented practice in PHP, you'll find that you'll be using `foreach` almost entirely, with `for` loops only for numerical or list-based things. `foreach` also prevents you from having to use `count($array)` to find the total number of elements in the array.

Answer (score 3):

`foreach` is specifically for iterating over elements of an array or object.

`for` is for doing something... anything... that has a defined start condition, stop condition, and iteration instructions.

So, `for` can be used for a much broader range of things. In fact, without the third expression - without the iteration instructions - a `for` becomes a `while`.

Examples:

```
// Typical use of foreach
// It's strength is iterating over arrays & objects
$people = array("Tom", "Dick", "Hairy");

foreach ($people as $person) {
    echo "$person <br/>"; }
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/eAtY9b)

Now you could do the exact same thing with `for`, but why bother? Instead `for` can be used for completely different things:

```
// Prints random names from array until Hairy is picked
for ($people = array("Tom", "Dick", "Hairy"); // initial condition
     $people[0] != "Hairy";                   // stop condition
     shuffle($people)                         // iteration instructions
    ) {
    echo "$people[0] <br/>";
}
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/8y5HsD)

The initial condition is done before the `for` loop once, no matter what. If the stop condition evaluates to `false` the loop will be immediately stopped. The change instructions are performed at the end of each loop. Notice that the change instructions don't have to be increments.

Here is an example of turning a `for` loop into a `while` loop by leaving out the iteration instructions.

```
// Does the loop a random number of times.
// No thired expression
for ($rand = function() {$array = array(true, true, true, true, false);
         shuffle($array);
         return $array;
        };                   
     current($rand()); 
     // empty third expression
 ) {  

    echo "I bring nothing to the table.<br/>";
}
```

[**Working example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/0TvwRT)

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty simple

`foreach` abstracts away some of the complexity and is usually easier. I use this whenever I don't need to know the numerical index of the array or `$key => $value` won't provide me with it.

`for` is the older C style where you must first perform a `count()` so you know how many iterations the loop requires. It is useful when you need to know the index, or to count backwards or step through in different groups.

Comment: `expr2` in a `for` can be whatever you consider the end condition. It does not have to be `count()`. For instance, with an Iterator you could do `for($it->rewind(); $it->valid(); $it->next()) { /* ... */}`, but it could also be a callback, db query, whatever.

Comment: @Gordon: I was about to say something similar. Everyone here seems to think that `for` loops can only be used with numbers...

Comment: @Felix @Gordon Well I tried to make it a simple example for traversing an array. But thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

A "for" loop gives you an incrementing number (in its most common use) which you can use any way you like.

"foreach" is a special construct made for looking at successive members of an array.

As an example, you can use a "for" loop to create something that does what "foreach" does.  But foreach does that with less required code.

Comment: `for` only gives you an incrementing number if you defined it to do so. The used expressions in a `for` are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0):

Foreach is basically a shortcut for doing the following

```
//Foreach method
foreach ($myArray as $myVar)
{
}

//Normal for equivalent
for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++)
{
$myVar = $myArray[$i];
}
```

But there are other issues too, [read this](http://derekgallo.com/2007/04/19/for-vs-foreach/) article about it

Answer (score 0):

`foreach` being used to iterate arrays and nothing else.
`for` is the general purpose counter-based loop

Comment: As of PHP 5, it is possible to iterate objects too.

Answer (score 0):

Better and easy answer is:
      Difference between Foreach and For Loop:-

```
  1. Foreach Loop:- Details are following.
    a) Foreach loop used when you have an array, without array it's not worked.
    b) Loop working at the end of array count. For example an array have 5 value 
     then   loop run 5 times.
    c) Syntax is following.
      $array = array("Surinder","Rahul","Manoj","Bharti","Rana","Manish");     
      Foreach($array as $name ){
         echo "Employe Name is ".$name.".";
      }
   This will print as following.
     Employe Name is Surinder.
     Employe Name is Rahul. 
     Employe Name is Manoj.
     Employe Name is Bharti.
     Employe Name is Rana.
     Employe Name is Manish.



 2. For Loop:- Details are following.
    a) For loop used according to condition.
    b) Loop working at the end of given condition.
    c) Syntax is following.
       $array = array("Surinder","Rahul","Manoj","Bharti","Rana","Manish");
       For($i=0;$i<6;$i++){
          echo "Employe Name is ".$array[$i].";
       }
    At the place of 6,You can used count array function.
    This will print as following.
    Employe Name is Surinder.
    Employe Name is Rahul.
    Employe Name is Manoj.
    Employe Name is Bharti.
    Employe Name is Rana.
    Employe Name is Manish.
    These are the difference between Foreach and for loop.
```

For more info go there:http://ibmphp.blogspot.com/2012/10/difference-between-foreach-and-for-loop.html

Answer (score 0):

**for** loop is used if we know already that how many times the script should be run but in the case of **foreach** loop, we don't have any idea about the number of iteration.

Also **foreach** loop is used to iterate only **arrays** and **objects**.

You can refer the link for better understanding the difference between **for** and **foreach** loop -

https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-for-and-foreach-in-php