# Limit the number of images to display php

Tags: php

this code causes the images to be displayed in a "random" within the page.

```
<?php
$myImagesList = array (
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png',
    'image4.png'
);



shuffle ($myImagesList);
foreach ($myImagesList as $displayImagesAtRandomOrder) {
echo '<img src="/imagens/' . $displayImagesAtRandomOrder . '" width="200" height="40" border="0" />';
}
?>
```

**example:**

image1.png image3.png image2.png image4.png

F5 reshesh page

image2.png image3.png image4.png image3.png

F5 reshesh page

image1.png image4.png image3.png image2.png

F5 reshesh page

image2.png image3.png image1.png image4.png

**But how do I get only two images are displayed at a time?
example:**

image1.png image3.png

F5 reshesh page

image3.png image2.png

F5 reshesh page

image2.png image4.png

F5 reshesh page

image3.png image1.png

Comment: `break` out of your loop after you've output the number of images you  want. Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588892/can-you-exit-a-loop-in-php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [limiting number of times a loop runs in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998204/limiting-number-of-times-a-loop-runs-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach is to just limit the iteration

```
<?php
$myImagesList = array (
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png',
    'image4.png'
);

$count = 1; //set up our count, start at our first image
$imagesToShow = 2; //how many images we want to show



shuffle ($myImagesList);
foreach ($myImagesList as $displayImagesAtRandomOrder) {
    //if we have reached our count, let's break out of our loop
    if($count > $imagesToShow) { break; }
    echo '<img src="/imagens/' . $displayImagesAtRandomOrder . '" width="200" height="40" border="0" />';
    $count++; //increase our count each loop iteration
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

After shuffling them, you can just loop twice taking the first two (0 and 1) items in the array:

```
shuffle ($myImagesList);
for ($i=0; $i<2; $i++) {
echo '<img src="/imagens/' . $myImagesList[$i] . '" width="200" height="40" border="0" />';
}
```

Comment: your i's don't have $ in front of them

Answer (score 0):

Use a `for-loop` instead of `foreach` with only 2 iteraction:

```
<?php

$myImagesList = array (
    'image1.png',
    'image2.png',
    'image3.png',
    'image4.png'
);

shuffle ($myImagesList);

for($index = 0; $index < 2; $index++){
    echo '<img src="/imagens/' . $myImagesList[$index] . '" width="200" height="40" border="0" />';
}

?>
```

If you don't know the difference beetwen the two keywords: [what are the difference between for loop & for each loop in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2590792/what-are-the-difference-between-for-loop-for-each-loop-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$imageCounter = 0;
foreach ($myImagesList as $displayImagesAtRandomOrder) {
  $imageCounter++;
  echo '<img src="/imagens/' . $displayImagesAtRandomOrder . '" width="200"   height="40" border="0" />';
  if (!($imageCounter % 2)) break;
}
```

The above code will only show 2 images. You can change that number to be any number you want. Hope it helps.